# PySpark: Incremental Row Counter

Tags: pyspark

I am having difficulty implementing this existing answer:
[PySpark - get row number for each row in a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513959/pyspark-get-row-number-for-each-row-in-a-group)

Consider the following:

```
# create df
df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([
    [1, 'A', 20220722, 1],
    [1, 'A', 20220723, 1],
    [1, 'B', 20220724, 2],
    [2, 'B', 20220722, 1],
    [2, 'C', 20220723, 2],
    [2, 'B', 20220724, 3],
]),
                           ['ID', 'State', 'Time', 'Expected'])

# rank
w = Window.partitionBy('State').orderBy('ID', 'Time')
df = df.withColumn('rn', F.row_number().over(w))
df = df.withColumn('rank', F.rank().over(w))
df = df.withColumn('dense', F.dense_rank().over(w))

# view
df.show()
```

```
+---+-----+--------+--------+---+----+-----+
| ID|State|    Time|Expected| rn|rank|dense|
+---+-----+--------+--------+---+----+-----+
|  1|    A|20220722|       1|  1|   1|    1|
|  1|    A|20220723|       1|  2|   2|    2|
|  1|    B|20220724|       2|  1|   1|    1|
|  2|    B|20220722|       1|  2|   2|    2|
|  2|    B|20220724|       3|  3|   3|    3|
|  2|    C|20220723|       2|  1|   1|    1|
+---+-----+--------+--------+---+----+-----+
```

How can I get the expected value and also sort the dates correctly such that they are ascending?

Comment: How come row num of `A 20220723 ` is 1, it suppose to be 2. Also `C 20220723` suppose to be 1.

Comment: The `State` did not change for `ID` == 1

Comment: Ambiguous question. What's the expected output?

Comment: Note `Expected` in the results

Comment: doesn't explain why expected of C is 2

Comment: @pltc `C` is 2 because it belongs to `ID` == 2 , and its date is `20220723` which is after `20220722` and before `20220724`. Note the sorting in the output is off.

Comment: Nothing is off, it's exactly as you defined. ID first and then Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you restart your count for each new `id` value, which means the `id` field is your partition field, not `state`.

an approach with `sum` window function.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('st_notsame', 
               func.coalesce(func.col('state') != func.lag('state').over(wd.partitionBy('id').orderBy('time')), func.lit(True)).cast('int')
               ). \
    withColumn('rank', 
               func.sum('st_notsame').over(wd.partitionBy('id').orderBy('time', 'state').rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))
               ). \
    show()

# +---+-----+--------+--------+----------+----+
# | id|state|    time|expected|st_notsame|rank|
# +---+-----+--------+--------+----------+----+
# |  1|    A|20220722|       1|         1|   1|
# |  1|    A|20220723|       1|         0|   1|
# |  1|    B|20220724|       2|         1|   2|
# |  2|    B|20220722|       1|         1|   1|
# |  2|    C|20220723|       2|         1|   2|
# |  2|    B|20220724|       3|         1|   3|
# +---+-----+--------+--------+----------+----+
```

- you first flag all the consecutive occurrences of the state as `0` and others as `1` - this'll enable you to do a running sum
- use the `sum` window with infinite lookback for each `id` to get your desired ranking