# cannot resolve cycle column in given input columns

Tags: pyspark, sas

```
DATA Account_cyc_2; 
  set Account_cy; 
  cycle+1; 
  by acc_no; 
  if firsr.acc_no then cycle=0; 
RUN;

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("acc_no").orderBy("some_column")

df_Account_cyc_2 = (
    df_Account_cyc_1
    .withColumn("cycle", lag("cycle", default=0).over(windowSpec) + 1)
    .withColumn("cycle", 
       when(df_Account_cyc_1["acc_no"] != lag(df_Account_cyc_1["acc_no"], 1)
      .over(windowSpec), 0)
      .otherwise(df_Account_cyc_1["cycle"])
    )
)
```

**but is showing cannot resolve "cycle" given input columns**

Comment: Please add your input data along with the expected output.

Comment: Are you trying to create an incremental value by account number? If so, this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513959/pyspark-get-row-number-for-each-row-in-a-group

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DipanjanMallick please see below is sas input                                                                    DATA Account_cyc_2; 
  set Account_cy; 
  cycle+1; 
  by acc_no; 
  if firsr.acc_no then cycle=0; 
RUN;                                                                                                                                 I want this in pyspark code

Comment: @s_pike what about if condition

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect the if condition to work. Can you provide an example of your input data and expected output?